# Error when building Window Azure Cloud Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I am getting error when building window azure cloud project in VS2010 like below

> Error 55  The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The
>   fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.  C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Cloud Service\1.0\Visual Studio
>   10.0\Microsoft.CloudService.targets   202 5   REST.Cloud

I need to stick with my naming convention of projects , how can i resolve this issue?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that _really_ the location of your project - under \Program Files(x86)??

Comment: No my project path is something like this E:\Projects\...

Comment: @Jeremeny. That is an MSBuild targets directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way around this. You'll need to move your project to a location with a reasonably short path.